# How do I make the forms of a pdf embeded in a website fillable html forms?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, pdf

I have embedded a pdf in my website using the html embed tag:

```
<embed src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/RegForm.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="2200px"/>
```

I want to make the pdf fillable so that the user input can be processed on my server.  How do I go about it ?

Here is the link to the actual pdf [Actual Pdf](https://www.dos.ny.gov/forms/licensing/1735-a.pdf)

Comment: The PDF you submitted does not contain AcroForm data, so no PDF reader would know there is anything to submit. Did you create the PDF? If not, who provides you the PDF files? Is this the only one? If more, are they very similar? If your corpus is similar, then you could possibly automate the addition of AcroForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PDF you are showing appears to be created by Adobe Acrobat. If you have Acrobat Pro, you can use the Prepare Form tool to add fields. If you have Standard, you'll need to find another tool. Most PDF editors have some degree of form authoring.

However, if you use the embed tag (or the object tag), there is no guarantee that the viewer your users view the form in will be able to fill the form and also submit the data. The embed tag relies on either the native browser PDF viewer or the OS level PDF viewer depending on the browser, browser version, and operating system. Don't expect ***any*** level of consistency for the end user and don't expect to collect all of the data on your server when a user fills the form in a browser.

I suggest you rethink your solution.

Comment: Would you suggest an html form and then processing the result as pdf ?

Comment: If you just need a PDf at the end, that would be my recommendation.

Comment: Thanks that s the solution